# Canvas Graph plotting data incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graph, plot

I have made a simple graph in a canvas but am having difficulty with two issues.

The first issue is setting the vertical axis with an appropriate scale automatically with enough room for each data value in an array. Ideally i'd like the numbers to be more rounded to the nearest million or thousand etc depending on it's actual value ranges rather than a value like `33145` as the first scale line.

Currently one value is too high for the scale and is not being drawn on the canvas because it is out of bounds.

The second issue, is the points don't seem to be plotting in their correct location, which I am unsure where my mistake was.

I made a JSFiddle as for the most part it might be a bit confusing without seeing it in action:

**http://jsfiddle.net/ezttywzr/**

This is how i plot my data and draw my vertical axis:

**Vertical Axis**:

```
    var x           = 0,
        y,
        range       = data.max() - data.min(),
        valueStep   = range / 10,

// get width of largest number
        margin      = 3 + ctx.measureText(data.min() + (valueStep*10)).width,

        pixelStep   = (graph.height-40) / 10,
        verticalP   = pixelStep,
        output;

// draw left hand values
    for(var i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        output = data.min() + (valueStep*i);                        

        y           = graph.height-20 - (verticalP + i*pixelStep);
        ctx.fillText(output,x,y+6); 

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(margin, y);
        ctx.lineTo(x2,y);
        ctx.stroke();

    }
```

**Data Plotting**:

```
    var y             = graph.height,
        x             = margin,
        pos,
        valueStep     = (graph.width-(margin*2)) / data.length,
        pixelRange    = graph.height-20,
        pp            = range / pixelRange;

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){   
        x   += valueStep;
        pos  = x - (valueStep/2);       

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, graph.height-20);
        ctx.lineTo(x, graph.height);
        ctx.stroke();       


        ctx.fillText('Week '+(i+1),pos-(ctx.measureText('Week '+(i+1)).width/2),y);             
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(pos,(graph.height-20)-(verticalP+(data[i]/pp)),2,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();
    }
```

Comment: Here's a SO Q&A showing how to keep your values within the canvas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638453/dynamic-scaling-for-canvas-graphs/22644216#22644216

Comment: Thanks for this ! I will incorporate it to make it easier for me in future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice job so far.

I made a few changes: http://jsfiddle.net/ezttywzr/2/

To get the scale I used

```
STEP = data.max() / NUM_HORIZONTAL_LINES
```

Where `NUM_HORIZONTAL_LINES` is the number of horizontal lines you want above the x-axis. In this case I used 10.

This means the first line will be `1 * STEP`, the second will be `2 * STEP`, the third will be `3 * STEP` and so on..

This scale is convenient because it guarantees that the max value fits on the graph. In fact, the max value is on the top line because of the way we defined the scale.

Once we have our scale it's easy to calculate the position of the points relative to the x-axis. It's simply:

```
(PIXELS_PER_STEP / STEP) * VALUE
```

To go a step further you can do some math to round the top point of the graph up and pick a scale with that has nice round numbers.